# What is the best way to loop this program?

Tags: vb.net, loops

This is one of the form, all the usercontrol value in this form will store in My.Settings

[image: form]

I have another form with a FlowLayoutPanel, everytime when the application start,
if Active checked then it will add a Button with discount value to the FlowLayoutPanel.

Should I add those usercontrol to a list and then loop through the list? Or what is the best way to solve this kind of problem?

UPDATED

How can I add multiple item to list in 1 code? I getting this error when system run to line 5

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XXX.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Public Sub RefreshDiscount(ByRef ref As scr_mainDiscount)
    Dim li_disName As New List(Of TextBox)
    Dim li_disValue As New List(Of TextBox)
    Dim li_disType As New List(Of ComboBox)
    Dim li_active As New List(Of CheckBox)
    Dim tb_disName As TextBox() = {ref.tb_name1, ref.tb_name2, ref.tb_name3, ref.tb_name4, ref.tb_name5, ref.tb_name6, ref.tb_name7, ref.tb_name8, ref.tb_name9, ref.tb_name10}
    Dim tb_disValue As TextBox() = {ref.tb_value1, ref.tb_value2, ref.tb_value3, ref.tb_value4, ref.tb_value5, ref.tb_value6, ref.tb_value7, ref.tb_value8, ref.tb_value9, ref.tb_value10}
    Dim cb_disType As ComboBox() = {ref.cb_type1, ref.cb_type2, ref.cb_type3, ref.cb_type4, ref.cb_type5, ref.cb_type6, ref.cb_type7, ref.cb_type8, ref.cb_type9, ref.cb_type10}
    Dim chkb_active As CheckBox() = {ref.CheckBox1, ref.CheckBox2, ref.CheckBox3, ref.CheckBox4, ref.CheckBox5, ref.CheckBox6, ref.CheckBox7, ref.CheckBox8, ref.CheckBox9, ref.CheckBox10}

    li_disName.AddRange(tb_disName)
    li_disValue.AddRange(tb_disValue)
    li_disType.AddRange(cb_disType)
    li_active.AddRange(chkb_active)

    For index As Integer = 0 To li_active.Count - 1
        If li_active(index).Checked = False Then
            li_disName.RemoveAt(index)
            li_disValue.RemoveAt(index)
            li_disType.RemoveAt(index)
            li_active.RemoveAt(index)
        Else
            Dim btn As New ctrl_DiscountButton
            With btn
                .Text = li_disName(index).Text
                .Price = li_disValue(index).Text
                .Type = li_disType(index).Text
            End With
            scr_sales.flp_discount.Controls.Add(btn)
        End If
    Next

    li_disName.Clear()
    li_disValue.Clear()
    li_disType.Clear()
    li_active.Clear()
End Sub
```

Comment: You can create all of this through code. Add them in a list or use FindControl, both options are valid.

Comment: What have you actually tried? I appreciate you're new to .NET but all of your questions appear to be akin to asking for code to be written for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example showing how to find CheckBox1 thru CheckBox10, "by name", using the "searchAllChildren" option of [Controls.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim ctlName As String = "CheckBox" & i
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is CheckBox Then
            Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(matches(0), CheckBox)
            ' do something with "cb"
            If cb.Checked Then
                ' ... code ... 
                ' possibly use code just like this to find the matching discount value control?
            End If
        End If
    Next
```